# Training LSTM network and predicting with different starting points

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

This is a simple example of using LSTM cell from tensor flow. I am generating a sin wave and training my network for ten periods and I'm trying to predict the eleventh period. The predictor values X are one epoch lag of the true y. After training, I save the session to the disk and I restore it at prediction time - this is typical of training and deploying models to production.

When I predict the last period, y_predicted is matching very well the true y.

If I try to predict the sin wave using an arbitrary starting point, (i.e. uncomment line 114)
test_data = test_data[16:]
such that the true values of y would be shifted by a quarter period, it seems like the LSTM prediction still starts at zero and it takes a couple of epochs to catch up with the true values, eventually matching the previous prediction. As a matter of fact it seems that the prediction in the second case is still a full sin wave instead of the 3/4 wave.

What is the reason why this is happening. If I implement a regressor I would like to use it starting with any point.

https://github.com/fbora/mytensorflow/issues/1

```html
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.rnn as rnn



def sin_signal():
    '''
    generate a sin function
    the train set is ten periods in length
    the test set is one additional period
    the return variable is in pandas format for easy plotting
    '''
    phase = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi*11, 0.1)
    y = np.sin(phase)
    data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'phase': phase, 'y':y})
    # fill the last element by 0 - it's the end of the period anyways
    data['X'] = data.y.shift(-1).fillna(0.0)
    train_data = data[data.phase<=2*np.pi*10].copy()
    test_data = data[data.phase>2*np.pi*10].copy()
    return train_data, test_data


class lstm_model():
    def __init__(self, size_x, size_y, num_units=32, num_layers=3, keep_prob=0.5):
        # def single_unit():
        #     return rnn.DropoutWrapper(
        #         rnn.LSTMCell(num_units), output_keep_prob=keep_prob)

        def single_unit():
            return rnn.LSTMCell(num_units)

        self.graph = tf.Graph()
        with self.graph.as_default():
            '''input place holders'''
            self.X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, size_x], name='X')
            self.y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, size_y], name='y')

            '''network'''
            cell = rnn.MultiRNNCell([single_unit() for _ in range(num_layers)])
            X = tf.expand_dims(self.X, -1)
            val, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X, time_major=True, dtype=tf.float32)
            val = tf.transpose(val, [1, 0, 2])
            last = tf.gather(val, int(val.get_shape()[0])-1)
            weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_units, size_y], 0.0, 1.0), name='weights')
            bias = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(size_y), name='bias')
            predicted_y = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(last, weights, bias, name='predicted_y')

            '''optimizer'''
            optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(name='adam_optimizer')
            global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False, name='global_step')
            self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(predicted_y, self.y), name='mse_loss')
            self.train_op = optimizer.minimize(self.loss, global_step=global_step, name='training_op')

            '''initializer'''
            self.init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()


class lstm_regressor():
    def __init__(self):
        if not os.path.isdir('./check_pts'):
            os.mkdir('./check_pts')


    @staticmethod
    def get_shape(dataframe):
        df_shape = dataframe.shape
        num_rows = df_shape[0]
        num_cols = 1 if len(df_shape)<2 else df_shape[1]
        return num_rows, num_cols


    def train(self, X_train, y_train, iterations):
        train_pts, size_x = lstm_regressor.get_shape(X_train)
        train_pts, size_y = lstm_regressor.get_shape(y_train)
        model = lstm_model(size_x=size_x, size_y=size_y, num_units=32, num_layers=1)

        with tf.Session(graph=model.graph) as sess:
            sess.run(model.init_op)
            saver = tf.train.Saver()
            feed_dict={
                model.X: X_train.values.reshape(-1, size_x),
                model.y: y_train.values.reshape(-1, size_y)
            }

            for step in range(iterations):
                _, loss = sess.run([model.train_op, model.loss], feed_dict=feed_dict)
                if step%100==0:
                    print('step={}, loss={}'.format(step, loss))
            saver.save(sess, './check_pts/lstm')


    def predict(self, X_test):
        test_pts, size_x = lstm_regressor.get_shape(X_test)
        X_np = X_test.values.reshape(-1, size_x)
        graph = tf.Graph()
        with graph.as_default():
            with tf.Session() as sess:
                sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
                saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./check_pts/lstm.meta')
                saver.restore(sess, './check_pts/lstm')
                X = graph.get_tensor_by_name('X:0')
                y_tf = graph.get_tensor_by_name('predicted_y:0')
                y_np = sess.run(y_tf, feed_dict={X: X_np})
                return y_np.reshape(test_pts)


def main():
    train_data, test_data = sin_signal()
    regressor = lstm_regressor()
    regressor.train(train_data.X, train_data.y, iterations=1000)
    # test_data = test_data[16:]
    y_predicted = regressor.predict(test_data.X)
    test_data['y_predicted'] = y_predicted

    test_data[['y', 'y_predicted']].plot()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that since you are starting your predictions at an arbitrary starting point in the future, there is a gap of values between what your model was trained on and what it is starting to see for predictions, and the State of your LSTM has not updated with the values in that gap?

*** UPDATE:

In your code, you have this:

```
val, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X, time_major=True, dtype=tf.float32)
```

and then during training this:

```
_, loss = sess.run([model.train_op, model.loss], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

I would suggest feeding the initial State into `dynamic_rnn` and re-feeding the updated state at each training iteration, something like this:

```
inState = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [YOUR_DIMENSIONS], name='inState')
val, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X, time_major=True, dtype=tf.float32, initial_state=inState)
```

And during training:

```
iState = np.zeros([YOUR_DIMENSIONS])
feed_dict={
                model.X: X_train.values.reshape(-1, size_x),
                model.y: y_train.values.reshape(-1, size_y),
inState: iState # feed initial value for state placeholder
            }
_, loss, oState = sess.run([model.train_op, model.loss, model.state], feed_dict=feed_dict) # run one additional variable from the session
iState = oState # assign latest out-state to be re-fed as in-state
```

So, this way your model not only learns the parameters during training, but also keeps track of everything that it's seen during training in the State. NOW, you save this State with the rest of your session and use it during the prediction stage.

The small difficulty with this is that technically this State is a placeholder, so it won't be saved in the Graph automatically in my experience. So you create another variable manually at the end of training and assign the State to it; this way it is saved in the graph for later:

```
# make sure this variable is declared BEFORE the saver is declared
savedState = tf.get_variable('savedState', shape=[YOUR_DIMENSIONS])
# then, at the end of training:
    assignOp = tf.assign(savedState, oState)
    sess.run(assignOp)
# now save your graph
```

So now once you restore the Graph, if you want to start your predictions after some artificial gap, then somehow you still have to run your model through this gap so as to update the state. In my case, I just run one dummy prediction for the whole gap, just so as to update the state, and then you continue at your normal intervals from here.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I believe that is the case too.  How can I update the state?

Comment: I noticed in your code in general that you are not passing the state around while training (i.e. not re-feeding the state from current iteration step to the next one). Is that intentional? If not, let me paste a few lines in the Answer, as there's not enough space here...

Comment: it's not intentional, i'm just a noob in tensor flow. :)

Comment: Aren't we all...) I updated the answer with some suggestions. Post here if need to clarify something...

Comment: how do you initialize a MultiRNNCell?  the state is a tupple, but the placeholder is tensor.  Do you need to reshape?

Comment: Ah yes, the annoying part. So in the example i posted, basically you have to specify state_is_tuple=False in the MultiRNNCell. That's a 'non-preferred' way to do things, but it works (i think it's a bit slower). If you want to keep it as tuple=True, then it's a bit more of a brain damage (on the prediction side, not on the training side). I've seen examples of the code, so if you search around you should be able to find. I just use this way, seems to work OK

Comment: apparently a lot of other people would like this kind of functionality. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2838

Comment: The dimensions of the state depend on size of the inputs (in my case placehoders X and y that do not specify the number of data points until runtime).  You can hard code the batch_size and feed the input in batches, but if your prediction is on a data set of different dimensions, how do you convert a state during training to a state during prediction if they have different shapes?  Is it possible to pass None to a placeholder and have a check at run-time, if it is none don't pass the state to dynamic_rnn and use the default zero state, if it's not None pass the place holder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147873/discussion-between-vs-ff-and-boraxis).